# Chrome extension cannot grab title from inactive tab

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have a Chrome extension that checks to see if the page is NYTimes.com.  If so, it stores the title of that page & sends it via PHP.  The listener itself works.  I can tell because the PHP side outputs a timestamp.  For every request, the timestamp is present.

The problem is that when I open a Tab by holding CTRL, it is not the active tab.  So a blank field is sent to my PHP file & I don't know the title of the page.  How would I get the data from a page that is loaded, but is not the active window?

```
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(result){
if (result.url.search("www.nytimes.com") >= 0 || result.url.search("nytimes.com") >= 0){
    title = result.title;
    $.post("http://myURL.com/tmp/test.php", {titletag: title});
    console.log("Saving "+result.title);
}
 });
```

Comment: FYI: Your if condition doesn't need the first clause. The second clause alone is enough as it is a substring of the first clause.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to be able to do the same thing :

Declare the injection of a javascript file in your manifest :

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://www.nytimes.com/*", "https://www.nytimes.com/*"],
    "js": ["my_script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```

Your my_script.js :

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({'title':document.title});
```

In your extension main script :

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(data) {
    $.post("http://myURL.com/tmp/test.php", {titletag: data.title});
}
```